# Checkbox in Form Helper Cake PHP

Tags: php, cakephp, checkbox

Here is the form helper I have used for checkbox

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->input('name',array('type'=>'checkbox','options'=>$options));
?>
```

and $options array is as follows:

```
 [options] => Array
                        (
                            [58] => 58
                            [85] => 85
                        )
```

But I am getting only one check box with both values in it. How can I get check box for each values.

Comment: You will need a foreach()

Comment: @Marijke We can do it without foreach() also.. I have marked correct answer which worked

Comment: Yup, that's a solution too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the multiple attribute.

```
   echo $this->Form->input('Name',array(
        'label' => __('Label',true),
        'type' => 'select',
        'multiple' => 'checkbox',
        'options' => $options,
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you have to check, and this is truly a general rule in `cakephp` when things do not run as expected. is:

> "Are you properly closing  the form? Do your inputs stay inside `<form>...</form>`? If you are not sure how to check simply use your preferred
>   DevTool and check the rendered HTML page.

This is almost the thing I forgot to check mostly and which always let me waste a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

**If your are creating the $option variable in the view this will help you :**

```
$options = array("key" => "value" , "key" => "value" , "key" => "value");
```

**But if you are setting it the controller this will help you :**

```
$this->set('options', array("key" => "value" , "key" => "value" , "key" => "value"));
```

- key is the value in each option of the select input
- value is the text of the option tags